# Algebraic Topology, Munkres, Section 2, Question 4: A simplex is a union of line segments connecting opposite faces that intersect only on one face

Tags: algebraic-topology

I've been mulling over this homework problem to excess so it's time I got some help. Any kind feedback is appreciated as I am trying to learn how to approach these problems. I think my difficulties are communication rather than concepts.

In Algebraic Topology by Munkres, Section 2 Problem 4, we're asked to show that a simplex is a union of the line segments connecting any two opposite faces (that is, $\{a_0, \dots, a_p\}$ and $\{a_{p+1}, \dots, a_n\}$ span opposite faces of the simplex spanned by all vertices $\{a_i\}$ with $i = 0, \dots, n$), and that if two distinct line segments intersect they do so at a point on one of the faces.

I'm fairly confident in the first part, here's my proof:

Consider the geometric span of $\sigma = \{a_0, \dots, a_n\} = \{\bar x = \sum\limits^n_{i=0}t_i \bar a_i, t_i \geq 0, \sum\limits^n_{i=0} t_i = 1\}$.

Consider the faces $\tau = \{a_0, \dots, a_p\}$ and $\rho = \{a_{p+1}, \dots, a_n\}$.

Clearly we have that $\sum\limits^n_{i=0}t_i \bar a_i = \sum\limits^p_{i=0}t_i a_i + \sum\limits^n_{i=p+1} t_i a_i$.

Given that $\sum\limits^n_{i=0} t_i = 1$ we may conclude that $1- \sum \limits^n_{i=p+1} t_i = \sum\limits^p_{i=0} t_i$. For brevity, let $c = \sum\limits^n_{i=p+1}t_i$ so we have $1- c = \sum\limits^p_{i=0} t_i$.

Consider $\sum \limits^n_{i=0} t_i \bar a_i = (1-c)\sum\limits^p_{i=0} \frac{t_i}{1-c} \bar a_i + c\sum\limits^n_{i=p+1} \frac{t_i}{c}\bar a_i$. Note that $\sum\limits^p_{i=0} \frac {t_i} {c-1} = 1$ and that $\sum\limits^n_{i=p+1} \frac{t_i}{c} = 1$ and that each $\frac{t_i}{1-c}$ and $\frac {t_i}c$ is non-negative, which is the condition for $\sum\limits^p_{i=0}\frac{t_i}{1-c}\bar a_i$ and $\sum\limits^n_{i=p+1} \frac{t_i}{c} \bar a_i$ to define the simplices $\tau$ and $\rho$ respectively.

Given any $0\leq\sum\limits^n_{i={p+1}} t_i =c \leq 1$ we have a line segment defined by two points, one on $\{a_0, \dots, a_p\}$ and the other on $\{a_{p+1}, \dots, a_n\}$. Thus $\sigma$ is the union of all such line segments. $\square$ (for first part)

Now we must prove that if two such lines intersect, they must intersect at at most one endpoint.

So I had written down a proof that said something to the effect of any subset of a simplex determines a simplex, so any two lines in question determine two simplices. If they intersect they determine a single simplex, which is then a simplicial complex. Their intersection must be a proper face, so we know that their intersection must be a vertex.

I'm however, not convinced of this, primarily the claim that a subset of a simplex is a simplex - I'm suspicious of additional conditions needed.

I've tried another approach, here it is:

Consider the two lines $l_1$ and $l_2$. They are distinct, so they are linearly independent. We assume that the system $\begin{bmatrix}c & (1-c) \\ d & (1-d) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \tau \\ \rho \end{bmatrix} = \vec b$  has a unique solution, which corresponds to their point of intersection.

In the case that both $\tau$ and $\rho$ are nonzero, the associated homogenous solution $\begin{bmatrix}c & (1-c) \\ d & (1-d) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \tau \\ \rho \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ , has only the trivial solution, namely $c,d =0$ and $(1-c) =0$ and $(1-d) = 0$. Since this solution is clearly impossible, we may conclude that either $\tau$ or $\rho$ must be zero. Without loss of generality, let $\rho$ be zero. This forces $c=d=0$ which indicates that our point of intersection will occur on the face of $\rho$. $\square$

Comment: What are "opposite faces" of a simplex"?  I can't locate the question you refer to in Munkres's "Elements of Algebraic Topology". Can you please be more specific about the reference and the question.

Comment: A simplex is defined as $\sigma = \{\bar x = \sum\limits^n_{i=0} t_i a_i \vert t_i \geq 0, \sum t_i = 1\}$.

The faces are defined as the simplices formed while fixing one or more $t_i = 0$.

Opposite faces are the geometric span of the complement (that is, $\{a_0, \dots, a_p\}$ and $\{a_{p+1}, \dots, a_n\}$ span "opposite" faces.

Answer (score 1):

Now we must prove that if two such lines intersect, they must intersect at at most one endpoint.

Suppose by contradiction that we have a point of intersection between two distinct lines.
Knowing that $s_i \geq 0$ if we have $\sum\limits^p_{i=0} s_i = 0$ we're done, since that forces $\sum\limits^p_{i=0}t_i =0$ which lands us on an intersection in $\tau$. Assuming they are distinct lines, they cannot have more than one point in common, so they do not intersect at $\rho$. Therefore, we may assume the case where neither of these sums are $0$.

Claim: we may assume that $\sum^p_{i=0}s_i \neq \sum^p_{i=0} t_i$ since if this were true, we would get a system of equations in 2 coordinates that would force our beginning and endpoints to be the same.

Proof of claim: let $ax + by = az + bw$ with $x,z \in \tau$ and $z,w \in \rho$.

Then we have $a(x-z) + b(y-w) = 0$.

Since $x,z \in \tau$ we know that all components past $p$ are zero, while likewise $y,w \in \rho$ imply that all components before $p+1$ are zero. This implies that $x = z$ and $y = w$.

Consider $\sum\limits^p_{i=0}t_i a_i  + (1- \sum\limits^p_{i=0}t_i)\rho_1 = (\sum\limits^p_{i=0} s_i a_i) + (1-\sum\limits^p_{i=0}s_i)\rho_2$ with the assumptions proved above.

Subtract

$\sum\limits^p_{i=0}(t_i - s_i) a_i = (1-\sum\limits^p_{i=0}t_i)\rho_2 -(1-\sum\limits^p_{i=0}t_i)\rho_1$

Divide through by $\sum\limits^p_{i=0}t_i - s_i$.

$\sum\limits^p_{i=0}\frac{(t_i - s_i)}{\sum\limits^p_{i=0}(t_i - s_i)} a_i = \frac{1 - \sum\limits^p_{i=0} s_i}{\sum\limits^p_{i=0}(t_i - s_i)}p_2 - \frac{1 - \sum\limits^p_{i=0} t_i}{\sum\limits^p_{i=0}(t_i-s_i)}\rho_1$

Note that the sum of the coefficients of $a_i$ is $1$.

The right hand side can be written by like so (by adding $0 = \sum t_i - \sum t_i$  to the left hand term and distributing the $-1$ on the right hand term):

$(1-\frac{1 - \sum\limits^p_{i=0} t_i}{\sum\limits^p_{i=0}(t_i - s_i)})p_2 +\frac{(\sum \limits^p_{i=0} t_i)-1}{\sum\limits^p_{i=0}(t_i - s_i)}\rho_1$

Notice that the sum of the coefficients of $\rho_2$ and $\rho_1$ is $1$

This implies that $\{a_0, \dots, a_p\}$ is in the plane spanned by $\rho$ (note that we're allowing coefficients to be negative) which contradicts the geometric independence of $\tau$ and $\rho$. Therefore, $s_i = t_i$ for $i = 0, \dots, n$. $\square$